# Git не могу сделать push

Tags: git, github, git-push

При попытке сделать пуш на гитхаб получаю ошибку:

Push failed
Failed with error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Все было нормально, а тут на новом проекте такое.. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 11):

После действий описанных в https://habrahabr.ru/post/266667/ всё заработало.
Опишу здесь, что сделал:

1. В папке с папкой git открыть GIT GUI Here;
2. Help-> Показать SSH -> если всё пусто, то жмём сгенерировать SSH;
3. Вставляем его в настройках Github;
4. Пробуем git push;
5. Если пользуетесь Intellij IDEA, то в настройках git (Ctrl+Alt+S->Version Control->git) выберете Built-in.
   При push будет запрашиваться пароль, который вы ввели при генерации SSH.

Comment: Отличный и простой гайд у vasiliyeskin, все заработало!

Comment: **1.В папке с папкой git открыть GIT GUI Here;** так что сделать надо я совершенно не понял этой фразы.

Answer (score 5):

Ошибка "Could not read from remote repository" означает что git не может прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Тут два варианта:

1. Внешний репозиторий по какой-то причине не работает или не доступен (проблемы на сервере, проблемы с сетью и т.п.)
2. Адрес репозитория по умолчанию не корректен. Можно проверить с помощью команды `git remote -v`.

Comment: Все вроде нормально, выдает origin и ссылку на нужный репозиторий

Comment: А ссылка https или ssh?

Comment: Ссылка вида git@github.com:_login_/репозиторий

Comment: Вот такая ошибка сейчас permission denied (publickey). fatal could not read from repository

Comment: Когда пытаюсь через IDE делать, то ошибка такая: java.io.IOException: Authentication failed: 
 at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.authenticate(SSHMain.java:298)
 at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:172)
 at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:137)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Что-то не так с ssh public key. см. https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Comment: Смотрел уже, генерировал несколько раз по инструкциям, все равно никак(

Comment: Проблема решена, изменил адрес origin репозитория на http...

Comment: @OlegLysenko поместите найденное решение в виде ответа ниже, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

может кому то поможет, я решил вопрос таким образом

если после  `git config -l` показывает  
 remote.origin.url=git@github.com:*login*/репозиторий 
нужно изменить адрес таким способом 
`git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/_login_/репозиторий`

после этого `git push -u -f origin master` 
и у меня всё заработало

Answer (score 1):

Если команда git remote -v работает корректно то можно открыть GIT GUI Here для данного локального репозитория и если там не пустой  SSH, то просто жмем кнопку push и у меня все сработало, хотя Intellij Idea выдовало такуюже ошибку. При этом до этого все изменения должны быть закомичены, а команда git status должна показывать что в локальном все число: nothing to commit, working tree clean.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете в Vs code, то вам нужно самому ввести команду в терминале `git push origin main` и ввести ключевое слово, придуманное при генерации ssh ключа.

Answer (score 0):

Очень мало опыта работы с гитом. Сам создал проблему и сам ее решил.
Ошибка была такая же, как у автора.

Мне помогло следующее:

- у меня ключ ssh был добавлен непосредственно в настройках аккаунта, а также в одном из репозиториев.
- при создании второго репозитория я также пытался добавить ключ ssh и в него, но выдало ошибку, что ключ уже используется

Решение оказалось простым: удалил ключ из первого реп. и оставил только в глобальных стройках аккаунта. После чего воспользовался стандартными командами, которые предлагает гит для создания и пуша. Все сработало